# Image over another already drawn image in CAPTCHA

Tags: java, graphics2d

I want to generate a captcha by myself without using any other API, but here are some issues. In my code I have treated each character as an image and then form some operation on them but now I want to rotate whole image with respect to its midpoint.

Here is my sample code:

```
       for (int i = 0; i < charsToPrint; i++) 
       {

            double randomValue =Math.random();
            int randomIndex = (int) Math.round(randomValue * (chars.length - 1));
            char characterToShow = chars[randomIndex];
            finalString.append(characterToShow);
            int charWidth = fontMetrics.charWidth(characterToShow);
            int charDim = Math.max(maxAdvance, fontHeight);
            //int halfCharDim = (int) (charDim / 2);
            charImage = new BufferedImage(charDim, charDim,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            charGraphics = charImage.createGraphics();
            charGraphics.setColor(textColor);
            charGraphics.setFont(textFont);
            int rn = ran.nextInt((20 - 10) + 1) + 10;
            x1=charDim/rn;
            int rn1 = ran.nextInt((20 - 10) + 1) + 10;
            y1=charDim/rn1;
            int charX = (int) ((0.5 * charDim - 0.5 * charWidth)+x1);
            int charY=(int) ((charDim - fontMetrics.getAscent()) / 2 +         fontMetrics.getAscent()+y1);
            charGraphics.drawString("" + characterToShow, charX, charY);
            float x = horizMargin + spacePerChar * (i) - charDim / 2.0f;
            int y = (int) ((height - charDim) / 2);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.drawImage(charImage, (int) (x+x1), (int)(y+y1), charDim,charDim, null,null);
            charGraphics.dispose();
        }
```

Comment: And what, exactly, is the problem you're facing...?

Comment: i am having a problem when i am trying to rotate whole image then the previous image is as it is in its place and rotated image is over the prevoius image but i just want the rotated image